# how to merge nested maps in immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

```js
import {Map} from 'immutable'

let map1 = Map({a:1,b:{c:2,d:3,e:1});
let map2 = Map({c:100,d:400});
```

how do I get `Map {a:1,b:{c:100,d:400,e:1}}` by merging map1 and map2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use immutable.js built in `mergeIn` function. You will have to tweak  `map1` slightly so that the nested Map is also an instance of `Map`

The following code does the job:

```
let map1 = Map({ a: 1, b: Map({ c: 2, d: 3, e: 1 })})
let map2 = Map({ c: 100, d: 400 })
let map3 = map1.mergeIn(['b'], map2)
```